# What's the best way to notify about malformed template instantiations?

Tags: c++

How can I make forbidden template instantiations clearly visible at compile time? I was thinking about throwing an exception by inheriting it:

```cpp
template<string message> struct exception {};


template<class T> struct non_void;

template<class T> using non_void_t = typename non_void<T>::type;

template<> struct non_void<void>: exception<string{"non_void: argument is void"}> {};

non_void_t<void> poorly_typed_object;
```

but gcc 10 simply complains aboue *some error*:

```
$ g++ -std=c++20 exc.cpp 
exc.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class T> using non_void_t = typename non_void::type [with T = void]’:
exc.cpp:11:16:   required from here
exc.cpp:7:25: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct non_void<void>’
    7 | template<class T> using non_void_t = typename non_void<T>::type;
```

and does not display anything about the erroneus instantiation's parent type, so the actual error message never appears in compiler's output.

Is there a way to make it more apparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making the failing specialization `non_void_t<void>` a constrained partial specialization that triggers a `static_assert` on instantiation:

```
#include <type_traits>
template<class T> concept Void = std::is_void_v<T>;
template<Void T> struct non_void<T> { static_assert(!std::is_void_v<T>, "argument is void"); };
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/Tbsz5r).

Comment: Thanks, that must be the simplest solution.